# prevent child component to re-render below context provider with memo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, memoization, react-context

I am using a context provider in React to share data across several components. However since a value gets changed from one of my subcomponents, it rerenders all of my other components which partly leads to performance issues. So I want to prevent my child components to rerender. I tried using React.memo() but it's still rendering whenever I set the state of the Context Provider.

```
const Authenticator = React.memo(() => {
  
  const [myChat, setMyChat] = useContext(ChatContext);

  console.log("rerender"); // gets called everytime on click
  return (
    <Button
      title="click me"
      onPress={() => setMyChat({ text: "hello" })}
    ></Button>
  );
});
```

My Context Provider looks like this:

```
const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [myChat, setMyChat] = useState([]);

  return (
    <ChatContext.Provider value={[myChat, setMyChat]}>
      {children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
<ChatProvider>
  <Authenticator />
</ChatProvider>
```

Answer (score 8):

`React.Memo` doesn't help since you are calling the `useContext` hook which will cause the component to re-render every time the value from the provider changes. You should consider splitting your context into two separate contexts: one for the value, one for the state updater.

```
const ChatProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [myChat, setMyChat] = useState([])

  return (
    <ChatDispatchContext.Provider value={setMyChat}>
      <ChatValueContext.Provider value={myChat}>
        {children}
      </ChatValueContext.Provider>
    </ChatDispatchContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Then, update your `Authenticator` component to the following:

```
const Authenticator = React.memo(() => {
  const setMyChat = useContext(ChatDispatchContext)

  return (
    <Button
      title="click me"
      onPress={() => setMyChat({ text: "hello" })}
    ></Button>
  )
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I am still not 100% sure I understood, because 1) how can I set my state from the Dispatch Provider in my ValueContext? 2) since the Dispatch Provider is above the Value Provider, it would also rerender the children? Can

Comment: 1. Calling `setMyChat` will update the state value in `ChatProvider` which will be passed to your components consuming `ChatDispatchContext`.  2. The order of the providers doesn't matter.  What matters is that your `Authenticator` component is using a context value which doesn't change (`setMyChat`).  This combined with `React.memo` will prevent the component from re-rendering.

Comment: Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gUHfe-ETuo&ab_channel=BenAwad

Comment: Is splitting into two contexts the only way @MarkSkelton? No chance to get them into the same Provider? Tried to wrap the context's methods with useCallback but no luck.

Comment: I believe you can do "const contextValue = React.useMemo(()=>[myChat, setMyChat], [myChat, setMyChat])" and pass on contextValue to the provider. That would only update the context whenever myChat changes

Comment: Look at the answer here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156